# Как настроить форму на отправку по e-mail?

Tags: html, php

Есть готовая форма, установлена на сайт. Единственное, что осталось сделать, это настроить отправку данной формы на почтовый ящик. Я не силен в PHP, нуждаюсь в подробных инструкциях, каким образом это реализуется.

Answer (score 3):

Для отправки письма существует стандартная функция (правда, не на всех хостингах она работает, если не работает, то рекомендую сторонний класс phpMailer [источник](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/), [источник](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/264-PHP-Full-featured-email-transfer-class-for-PHP.html) ):

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

где:

> - `$to` - получатель
> - `$subject` - тема письма ( рекомендую использовать так:
>   `'=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?='`; если у вас кодировка другая, впишите другую
> - `$messag`e - тело сообщения
> - `$additional_headers` - опциональный ( необязательный ) параметр. о нём подробней

Если вы хотите отправить сообщение в виде html, то нужно в этот параметр записать следующее:

```
"Content-Type: text/html;charset='UTF-8'\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
```

если обычный текст, то:

```
"Content-Type: text/plain;charset='UTF-8'\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
```

Этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы отправить письмо.

**UPD:**

если вы хотите добавить кого-либо как получатель копии сообщения, нужно добавить в `$additional_headers` следующие строки:

```
$additional_headers .= "CC: a.pupkin@mail.ru, a.pupkin2@mail.ru\r\n"
```

если вы хотите добавить кого-либо как получатель скрытой копии сообщения (тот, кому вы отправили письмо не увидит что была еще послана копия), нужно добавить в `$additional_headers` следующие строки:

```
$additional_headers .= "BCC: a.pupkin@mail.ru, a.pupkin2@mail.ru\r\n"
```

если вы хотите добавить обратный адресс ( нужно в случае, если вы хотите что бы отвечали на письмо на другой адресс, не с того с которого было выслано письмо, нужно добавить в `$additional_headers` следующие строки:

```
$additional_headers .= "Reply-To: a.pupkin@mail.ru\r\n"
```

Comment: На моей форме много полей, каждому полю задано имя. Значит на каждое имя необходимо задавать переменные в обработчике? Хостинг отправку почты поддерживает.

Comment: А какие поля нужны еще ?
Копия, скрытая копия, обратный адресс ?

Просто это всё ближе к стандарту mime и не относится к php. Нужно освтятить эти вопросы тоже ?

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте mail патч на php, документация к нему есть на php.ru

Answer (score 0):

Либо принимаешь на сервере и шлёшь письмо, либо так:

```html
<form action="mailto:somebody@somemail.ru" enctype="text/plain">
  <input type=text name=smth required>
  <input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
```